# Is there any difference between a static variable and a static inline variable in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

1. An inline function or inline variable (since C++17) has the following properties:

- The definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed (not necessarily before the point of access).

2. An inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage (e.g. not declared static) has the following additional properties:

- There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is included in multiple source files.
- It must be declared inline in every translation unit.
- It has the same address in every translation unit.

Since only the first point is relevant to static variables, I don't quite understand the effect of the *inline* specifier for *static* variables. Isn't it true for any *static* variable that its definition must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed? Is there any other difference?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, `inline` doesn't do anything for variables at namespace scope with internal linkage (static global variables). I suspect it's just allowed for symmetry with other usages; it would have complicated the rules of the language to explicitly prohibit such combination.